# Check condition with map in visualforce

Tags: jquery, map

I get a list of value from rest API call and bind the json in visualforce page using jquery template. I have a problem here

I have a map with particular values. I need to check if the json result has any values in the map and display it in vf page.

I need to compare the map with json result without using repeat, page blocktable since we are using jquery template to bind data..

Any ideas??

Comment: Can you please share whatever you have tried so far?

Comment: Since I don't have only posted it. I just need to check the possibility of checking the map in visualforce page. I googled a lot and it is requires a repeat to loop through.. But as I am using jquery template I need to check if the map javascrpt

Comment: because no code is  showed, can I assume that your issue might be similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474940/get-value-from-json-with-jquery-without-using-foreach-loop .Because you dont want to use looping.